# EventToCommand not working when migrate to v4 for SL5

Tags: mvvm-light, silverlight-5.0

I have SL4 app with MVVMLight. I migrate it to SL 5 and got following error when compiling the app:

The tag 'EventToCommand' does not exist in XML namespace 
'clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.SL5

The xaml for this error is:

```
  xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
  xmlns:cmd="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.SL5"

<i:Interaction.Triggers>
   <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonUp">
       <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding ResetPasswordCommand,Mode=OneWay}"                                             
        MustToggleIsEnabledValue="True" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

quite confused.  Have update all assemblies for new platform. How to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Figure it out: should use assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.SL5 instead of assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.SL5.
Thanks.