# EventToCommand Missing For Windows Phone App

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, mvvm-light

I'm building Windows Phone 8 app using MVVM Light. So far, so good. 
 However, when I used EventToCommand, I get multiple errors. One similar question is here [EventToCommand not working when migrate to v4 for SL5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11510233/eventtocommand-not-working-when-migrate-to-v4-for-sl5), but sadly it doesn't solve my problem.! It automatically adds following reference:

```
xmlns:command1="http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvmlight"
```

Errors that I receive:

The name "EventToCommand" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.WP8"

The type 'command:EventToCommand' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.

The tag 'EventToCommand' does not exist in XML namespace 'clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.WP8'

Let me know if I'm missing anything or doing something wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is the correct xmlns (you were missing **Extras** in the assembly name):

```
xmlns:Command="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.WP8"
```

Answer (score 4):

Replace it with

```
xmlns:command1="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.WP8"
```

Answer (score 4):

With the recent version the command moved to Platform assembly:

```
xmlns:command="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Platform"
```