# EventToCommand missing on MVVM Light

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, mvvm, mvvm-light, eventtocommand

This helpful class seems to be gone from the latest MVVM Light build, any idea why or how to work around it?

I'm using MvvmLightLibs.5.0.1.0, was definitely there on MvvmLightLibs.4.1.27.0. So this question is not related with one [EventToCommand Missing For Windows Phone App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19550099/eventtocommand-missing-for-windows-phone-app)

Environment: VS2013, WP8.0

Comment: Laurent Bugnion [posted](http://blog.galasoft.ch/posts/2014/01/using-the-eventargsconverter-in-mvvm-light-and-why-is-there-no-eventtocommand-in-the-windows-8-1-version/) about this. It's for WP8.1 though.

Comment: @hantoun I got to the same article googling, but it's not related with my question, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Eventually, I found the `EventToCommand` class on Galasoft.MvvmLight.Platform. I guess the assembly change makes sense being a multi-platform framework.

```
 xmlns:Command="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Platform"

 <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Tap" >                
            <Command:EventToCommand  Command="{Binding Path=MyVM.MyCommand, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" 
                                     PassEventArgsToCommand="False"    
                                     CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Comment: See [also](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27430160/774575).