# How to pass event arguments from view to view model?

Tags: c#, .net, mvvm-light

I had a project which its version was .NET 4.0 and I changed it to 4.5.1. Then, I uninstall my MVVM Light 4.0 and install the new MVVM Light, that is 5.0.0.1.

However, now I don't have the EventToCommand and I would like to pass the arguments of an event to the view model. For example, when I select an item in a DataGrid, I want to know in the ViewModel which item is selected, and since this property is not a dependency property, I use MVVM Light to pass this.

So how can I pass the arguments from an event from the view to the view model?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From their [site](http://blog.galasoft.ch/posts/2014/10/announcing-mvvm-light-v5-for-windows-and-xamarin/), it is mentioned that:
This version doesn’t include `EventToCommand`, please use `InvokeCommandAction` instead.

There is another solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26421397/eventtocommand-missing-on-mvvm-light), which might help you.