# WP8 MvvmLight namespace missing and EventToCommand doesn't exist

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, mvvm, mvvm-light

I am using MVVM Light libraries only (from Nuget package) in my Windows Phone 8 project and I want to use `EventToCommand` in `ToggleSwitch`. I have these lines of codes:

```
<toolkit:ToggleSwitch x:Name="LockSwitch"
        IsChecked="{Binding IsLock, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Toggled">
            <Command:EventToCommand 
                Command="{Binding DataContext.NavigateToArticleCommand, ElementName=LayoutRoot}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</toolkit:ToggleSwitch>
```

The problem is that VS shows errors:

> Error 1   The name "EventToCommand" does not exist in the namespace
>   "clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.WP8".
>
> Error 2   The type 'Command:EventToCommand' was not found. Verify that
>   you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced
>   assemblies have been built.
>
> Error 3   The tag 'EventToCommand' does not exist in XML namespace
>   'clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.WP8'.

I have lines above in file Styles.xaml which is a `ResourceDictionary` and `ToggleSwitch` is part of a `DataTemplate`. I am including MvvmLight library using this line:

```
xmlns:Command="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.WP8"
```

What's wrong? Why I get that error? I was trying to use google but I couldn't find a solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reference that you use to include the command is wrong. The correct reference is

```
xmlns:Command="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Platform"
```

---

There's a trick to obtain this reference without writing a single line of code.

After you have downloaded the MvvmLight nuget package, compile your project and then open your xaml file in Expression Blend.

Then click the **Assets** icon on the left toolbar (the bottom one) and start typing "eventtocommand" (see picture below).

[image]

Once you see *EventToCommand* appear in the **Assets** panel, drag and drop it on top of your `ToggleSwitch`. That's it! The reference will be added into your xaml automatically as well as the actual command code.

Comment: Thanks, updated mvvmlight version only to find the namespace where EventToCommand is was changed.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `Microsoft.Behaviors SDK` ? (references, add reference, extensions, behavior sdk) Not sure but I think `EventTrigger` and mvvm light `EventToCommand` is deprecated now (because of behaviors sdk).

Code sample with Behaviors.SDK:

```
xmlns:interactivity="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
xmlns:core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"

<toolkit:ToggleSwitch x:Name="LockSwitch"
        IsChecked="{Binding IsLock, Mode=TwoWay}">
            <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Toggled">
                    <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding command}" CommandParameter="{Binding param}"/>
                </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
            </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
</toolkit:ToggleSwitch>
```

Comment: I guess it's for WP 8.1 right? I am developing for WP8 (Silverlight project).

Comment: @LiborZapletal - yes sorry. it's for winrt/wp8.1.